# Meaning of Smartctl output

Tags: linux, hard-disk, smartctl

I'd like to use `smartctl` to see how long each of my external hard drives has been running (for planned replacement) though I don't understand the man page.  I can't see what command I should be running or  make sense of the output

I use several external hard drives for a rotating backup

Here is a command that I've tried:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
```

( I have no idea why I have to prepend sudo - it won't run otherwise)

Anyway here is a fragment of the output (it is for an old portable Seagate 500GB drive connected via a USB 3 cable that also provides the drive power):

```
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   108   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       17374200
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1463
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   067   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       4300708401
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       2985 (94 211 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1269
```

I'm wondering if Power_On_Hours and Power_Cycle_Count are meaningful to gauge the operating lifetime so far. There are lots of columns after the parameter names, though I can't find a human explanation for them.

**Questions**

1. Are the units of the last column, i.e. 2985 for the Power_On_Hours row, literally that there have been 2985 aggregate number of operating hours for the disk since manufacture?  Similarly is the last column for Power_Cycle_Count literally that the disk has been plugged/unplugged 1269 times? (... or mount / umount?)
2. What are the units of the VALUE, WORST and THRESHOLD columns?
3. What is the Type column communicating? Is "Pre-fail" better or worse than "Old_age" or just different?
4. Where can I find out about the "Vendor specific  attributes"?
5. Are there other helpful ways of running smartctl for this purpose?

Many thanks in advance for any inspiration!

Comment: You're missing a load of attributes from that table, which help interpret the results

Comment: "_I have no idea why I have to prepend sudo - it won't run otherwise_" - you need administrator rights to read the raw disk device

Comment: SMART data is one of the tools to assess the health of a drive. If you have critical data on the drive, it's essential to maintain backups and consider replacing the drive if you notice significant degradation or signs of failure.

The `sudo`, `root` privileges requirement, because `smartctl` accesses low-level drive information, which is why it needs elevated permissions.

Comment: @roaima re. other attributes, yes sounds likely, but without any specific guidance that neatly illustrates the point, all there is to go on is the names with no units. Can you offer any specifics (e.g. my questions 1 - 4) on any of them, such as Attributes 9 and 12 or, as you suggest, any others?

Comment: @roaima #2 - thanks, I think the penny has dropped. It has been confusing though because many online resources about smartctl don't include sudo in the command string.

Comment: @BlockchainOffice Thanks, just edited, though this is the whole point of the question, rightly or wrongly I am assuming that there is data hidden away in the smartctl output that helps "notice significant degradation or signs of failure" though I don't find the man page clear enough to help with that at all.